# I've imported a .svg file into blender. How do i select all the curves in order to alt+c them into a mesh?

Tags: mesh

I have designed a spider gear for a project, however i now need to represent it as a 2d orthographic drawing.
I have created 2 .svg files one with the hidden lines and the second with the visible lines which, when combined, should give me a 2D representation of the 3D object.
My problem is that when i try and select the curves in order to alt+c them into a mesh i can only select 1 curve at a time (there are 1000+ curves per svg file).
Is it possible to select all of the curves at once then alt+c them?
I tried using select all (a) but it wont let me press alt+c.[image]

Comment: Don't blindly convert to a mesh unless strictly necessary, it is a destructive process

Comment: Suspect the issue here could be that non-curve (or non-convertable) objects are selected (camera for instance).  Try selecting all by type, or converting directly after the import when all newly added geom is selected (untested for svg, but is regular MO for  most importers)

Answer (score 0):

Join all your curves with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd>, then <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: Can you add more detail?